# Plotting fidelity graph

Tags: c, windows, plot

I want to plot a graph for fidelity with respect to time.
My function is

[image: F(t)=e^{-|\alpha|^2} e^{|\alpha|^2cos^2(t)}e^{-|\alpha\sin(t)|^2}]

Here F is fidelity and consider alpha = sqrt of 5.

How to plot this?
Can you give me some model programming code and recommend me some online site for plotting this?

Comment: Instead of F it should be F(t). Can you edit this in my question?

Comment: You may have a better experience posting this to https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Plot Online (wolframalpha.com)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20e%5E%7B-%7C%5Calpha%7C%5E2%7D%20e%5E%7B%7C%5Calpha%7C%5E2cos%5E2%28t%29%7De%5E%7B-%7C%5Calpha%5Csin%28t%29%7C%5E2%7D%20with%20alpha%3D%E2%88%9A5%2C%20from%20t%3D-1%20to%201)

When it comes to programming, that depends on the desired output. This could be only the screen (gdi, directx, opengl), raster graphics (bmp, jpg, png, ...) or vector graphics (svg, gltf, ...).

But before you (can) put anything out, you would have to calculate the plot points first. Here you definitively need the [standard math library (math.h)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math).

Once you have your set of points, you could plot them by using additional software like [plotutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/plotutils/).

Comment: I am using windows. Can you suggest me some other softwares?

Comment: And i am using linux, i am very lost in the windows world, but GNU plotutils is opensource and available for all major operating systems. But if you google "plot software windows" you will find many alternatives, e.g. (random pick of a quick search) [7 best free plotting software for 3D and 2D](https://windowsreport.com/free-software-graph-plotting/).